# Can addons be written in C to modify parts of Blender inaccessible through Python?

Tags: add-on, source-code

My experience with and understanding of coding is currently limited to three college courses on programming for business with Java, but I'm trying to learn how to code stuff for Blender.

I want to write some addons for new modifiers and texture nodes (like real texture nodes that would be listed along with Image, Noise, Musgrave, etc, not just "custom" nodes).  I've read that modifiers are written deep in the guts of Blender's C-based files, and are inaccessible through the Python interface; I figure the same would go for textures.  Are these files accessible, (if so, what/where are they), and can addons be written in C that would interact with them and expand on them?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would help, but you can check out Curtis Holt's video on the topic of Python + Blender: youtu.be/XqX5wh4YeRw

Comment: Not really.  Suggest the C / C++ part would be a patch adding your new modifier or new node also wiring it into the python API.  The user would have to build blender from patched source.  There are always a number of unofficial patches and those by way of git branches that are adding to or improving functionality (or neither) of blender.  Look for more info on https://developer.blender.org

Comment: @batFINGER Sorry, you'll have to pardon my coding ignorance; what are patches and branches?